# Is it possible to find a value inside an Array of Objects from an ID from another Array of Objects?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, loops, dictionary, object

I try to check if an ID from an Array of Objects is currently in my cart Array which contains Objects too. Is there any way to make it work with good performance?
React also shows an Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

My Code:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const UpsellItems = [
  {
    searchId: "Cart Id 1",
    suggestionId: "Id 1",
    message: "1",
  },
  {
    searchId: "Cart Id 2",
    suggestionId: "Id 2",
    message: "2",
  },
];

const CartUpsell = ({ cart }) => {
  const [upsell, setUpsell] = useState("");

  UpsellItems.map((UpsellItem) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
      if (cart[i]._id === UpsellItem.searchId) {
        setUpsell(UpsellItem.message);
        break;
      }
    }
  });

  return <div className="">{upsell}</div>;
};

export default CartUpsell;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never call `setState` inside component. It need to call inside a function or `hooks effect`.

In this case, you should call in the `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  UpsellItems.map((UpsellItem) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
      if (cart[i]._id === UpsellItem.searchId) {
        setUpsell(UpsellItem.message);
        break;
      }
    }
  });
}, [])
```